# Circular permutation of key ring

Tags: permutations, combinations

> How many ways can we arrange 6 distinct keys in a circular key ring?

I know that
$$\#(\text{Permutations of }n\text{ objects around circular path})=(n-1)!$$
But why do we divide by 2 in some cases? Do we divide here for $\frac{5!}2$ or do we leave it as $5!$? Why?

Answer (score 3):

On a ring, the following permutations are equivalent:

$$123456,234561,345612,456123,561234,612345$$

Hence $(n-1)!$.

If we count reflections as distinct, i.e.

$$123456\not\equiv 654321$$

we have a [necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)), if not, we have a bracelet, and we divide by $2$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why need divide by two also. I was pretty confused as what it means by key chain being up. Your two sequences sorted out this difference. Also, thanks for introducing terms of necklace and bracelet (one here).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you consider the arrangements related by turning the ring over to be equivalent or not.  If you seat people around a table, it seems clear to consider ABCDEF clockwise different from AFEDCB clockwise.  If you have keys on a ring, maybe you can't tell which side of the ring is up.  Turning the ring over reverses clockwise and counterclockwise, so we would consider these two the same.  If we do, we need to divide by two.